# Libfreenect won't install properly on 12.04 Hydro

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use libfreenect with a kinect. The output when I run

`roslaunch freenect_launch freenect-xyz.launch`

is

```
[ INFO] [1413756004.829132537]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1413756004.829250239]: 1. device on bus 000:00 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id '0000000000000000'
[ INFO] [1413756004.831311636]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1413756004.843299915]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: [ERROR] Unable to open specified kinect
```

The next command I ran was

`rosrun libfreenect glview`.

This returned

`[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named glview below /opt/ros/hydro/share/libfreenect`

So I tried

```
alex@alex-OptiPlex-GX620:~$ rospack find libfreenect
/opt/ros/hydro/share/libfreenect
alex@alex-OptiPlex-GX620:~$ cd /
alex@alex-OptiPlex-GX620:/$ cd /opt/ros/hydro/share/libfreenect
alex@alex-OptiPlex-GX620:/opt/ros/hydro/share/libfreenect$ ls
package.xml
```

From my understanding this means the proper packages that should come with libfreenect have not been installed. I have tried re-installing with no success. I have run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I have made sure to run

```
sudo modprobe -r gspca_kinect
echo 'blacklist gspca_kinect' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

The kinect is being connected by USB 2.0. The result of lsusb is

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:02c2 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c018 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 413c:2105 Dell Computer Corp. Model L100 Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195321/libfreenect-won%27t-install-properly-on-12.04-hydro/) by [kinect_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20330/kinect_guy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2014-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue is the model of the Kinect itself. Version 1473 is currently experiencing issues with the freenect library. Furthur discussion here: https://github.com/ros-drivers/freenect_stack/issues/12

---

Originally posted by [kinect_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20330/kinect_guy/) with karma: 38 on 2014-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`dpkg -L ros-hydro-libfreenect` shows that glview is installed into /opt/ros/hydro/bin/glview

Since this is the ROS bin directory (which is added to your PATH), this means that you should be able to run glview without rosrun:

```
. /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
glview
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kinect_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20330/kinect_guy/) on 2014-10-20**:
Yes, that does work. It outputs

```
Kinect camera test
Number of devices found: 1
Could not open device
```

Do you have any tips why it is unable to open the device?

See my first example as well

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-20**:
The permissions for your device are probably not set properly. The Ubuntu packages include a udev rule that should set up the permissions properly; try `sudo apt-get install freenect`

**Comment by [kinect_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20330/kinect_guy/) on 2014-10-20**:
Your tip has led me to try some other methods, none of which have worked. I tried

`sudo chmod o+w /dev/bus/usb/001/010` /001/010 being the bus and device of XBox NUI Camera.

I also tried `nano /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` as replacing "SYSFS" with "ATTR" should help.

**Comment by [kinect_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20330/kinect_guy/) on 2014-10-20**:
The above directory looks like (for the USB device):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:21:2f:30:79:c4", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
```

PS if it wasn't clear I did try your suggestion.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-20**:
no... that's the udev rule that ensures consistent naming of your wireless interface. You probably shouldn't mess with it.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-20**:
http://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Use_as_normal_user describes how to set up the udev rules manually.

**Comment by [kinect_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20330/kinect_guy/) on 2014-10-20**:
This does not work either. `glview` still cannot open the device. I tried restarting, ensured the proper kernel is blacklisted and the normal user directory was correct. Any other ideas are appreciated.

Is there a way to manually change the kinect to index = 1 like freenect_launch is looking for?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-20**:
What are the current permissions on the USB device? Try `ls -l /dev/bus/usb/001/`

**Comment by [kinect_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20330/kinect_guy/) on 2014-10-20**:
Output:

```
total 0
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root  189, 0 Oct 20 19:00 001
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root  189, 1 Oct 20 19:00 002
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root  189, 4 Oct 20 19:00 005
crw-rw-rw- 1 root audio 189, 5 Oct 20 19:00 006
crw-rw-rw- 1 root video 189, 6 Oct 20 19:00 007
```

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-20**:
Is your user a member of the `audio` and `video` groups? (Hint: what is the output from `groups`?)

**Comment by [kinect_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20330/kinect_guy/) on 2014-10-20**:
Yes it is. From the link you provided I ran

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G video alex
```

Where alex is the user. I did the same command replacing video with audio.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-20**:
That looks correct. Are you sure it still has permissions issues?

**Comment by [kinect_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20330/kinect_guy/) on 2014-10-20**:
When I run `glview` it is still unable to open the device. Freenect_launch will not work either.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-20**:
I'm out of good ideas. You could always try running `strace glview` to see all of the OS calls that are made and try to figure out which file is having permissions problems, but the results will be incredibly verbose and difficult to interpret.

**Comment by [kinect_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20330/kinect_guy/) on 2014-10-20**:
Thanks for your help during this process. I re-installed ROS Hydro and am having the same issues. I will update the thread if I find a solution.